# Android MQTT Paho project don't connect in the broker mosquitto

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get this [voice recognition project](https://github.com/emmano/voicerecog4pi) working with a Raspberry Pi and Android phone.

I'm running mosquitto (mqtt broker) on the Raspberry Pi. The Java application (jar file) and MyMQTT app (from the Play store) connect normally - I can tell this by controlling the LED on the Raspberry Pi via MyMQTT.

The `MQTTPhone` application in the project fails to connect to the mosquitto broker.

I'm using this code now only to test...

```
public class MqttService {
    public void doDemo() {
        try {
            MqttClient client = new MqttClient("tcp://192.1XX.1.1YY:1883", MqttClient.generateClientId());
            client.connect();

            client.subscribe("ZZZ.jstnow.mqtt.topic/Home/YYYYY/XXX");

            // We’ll now idle here sleeping, but your app can be busy
            // working here instead
            while (true) {
                try { Thread.sleep (1000); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }
        catch (MqttException e) { e.printStackTrace (); }
    }
}
```

I'm using iptables, port forwarding in the router, etc.

Please help me.

Comment: Do you see anything in the mosquitto log that shows your test application trying to connect? Are any of the exceptions thrown? I guess you are using the Paho java client, although you don't make that clear. What version of the Paho client are you trying to use?

Comment: Question 1: Yes, I have log in the screen and I don't see MQTTPhone application connected. But When I use MyMqtt, this connected.I'm using Paho java client org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.jar and/or I used org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.0.jar. When I tried with this project: (https://github.com/dirkmoors/MqttService/tree/master/src/com/qonect/protocols/mqtt), using ip of the raspberry pi with mosquitto, I has success.